# How can I run a script as sudo and for it to not ask me for a password?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script, root

I want to run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if grep -qs 'MinecraftServer' /media/kiancross/MinecraftServer/MinecraftServer; then
    echo "Disk already mounted, server boot will continue"
else
     mount /dev/sda1 /media/kiancross/MinecraftServer
fi

sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/kiancross/MinecraftServer
cd /media/kiancross/MinecraftServer/MinecraftServer/1.6.4
screen -d -m -S MinecraftServer ./start.sh
screen -r MinecraftServer
```

My problem is, is that mount requires sudo and I want people who are not administrators to be able to run this script. When I run the script, it says `mount: only root can do that` then it asks me for my administrator password.

I followed instructions on other forums that recommended you go to `sudo visudo`
 then add the following line of code: `myusername ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/my/program`. After trying this, even with a restart I was still asked to ewnter my password. I also tried changing the owner of the file to `root` by following the instructions in this post.

After doing that, I was still unable to run it without a password.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What is the exact line that you added to your sudo rules?

Comment: @JennyD The exact line I added to my sudo rules was `kiancross ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /kiancross/bin/`

Comment: One answer coming up, in a few minutes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways that you can do this.

#### 1: Using sudo

One is to allow everyone to use sudo to mount the disk. The sudo line should look like this:

```
ALL ALL = NOPASSWD: mount /dev/sda1 /media/kiancross/MinecraftServer
```

The first ALL means "all users"; the second means "on any server where this sudoers file is installed". You also need to have the full path to the actual command, not just the directory.

If you do that, you also need to change the script so that the `mount` command is always run using with `sudo`, like this:

```
 sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/kiancross/MinecraftServer
```

#### 2: Using mount options

Another way is to change the mount options for /dev/sda1 so that it can be mounted by any user - that way you won't need to use sudo at all. To do this, change your /etc/fstab so that the line with that disk reads something like

```
/dev/sda1 /media/kiancross/MinecraftServer YOURFSTYPE users,exec
```

Where it says `YOURFSTYPE` you should of course write what filesystemtype your disk is - probably ext4.

The alternatives `users,exec` means that the file system can be mounted by a regular user, and that programs on it can be executed. You have to specify this because usually if a file system is mounted by someone other than root, files on it won't be executed.

Comment: After adding the line in option 1 I am told that there is a syntax error. Also, I followed the instructions in option 2 and it didn't work for me, it still asked for the password.

Comment: I changed the sudoers line, try again.

Comment: Nope, still getting the syntax error. Can I just confirm I am putting it in the right place? I am using `sudo visudo` then putting it in the file that opens?

Comment: @JennyD IIRC user-mounting requires `mount` to be setuid.

Comment: @peterph What does that mean. How can the code be corrected?

Comment: @crossboy007 you'd have to check `mount` has the setuid bit set - i.e. whoever calls it, the effective rights with which it will run will be those of the owner of the executable (usually `root`) - you'd see an `s` instead of an `x` in the file access mode for the owner when you list it e.g. with `ls -l`.